# 12-column system is not responsive on mobile

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a responsive 12-column grid system like Bootstrap.

The code works well on desktop when I change the browser window, but when I open the HTML file in mobile it’s not responsive. Check my CSS code for row and column (12 columnn) and help me make it perfect.

```css
.col .row {
  margin-left: -0.75rem;
  margin-right: -0.75rem;
}

.row {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.row .col {
  float: left;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0 0.75rem;
  min-height: 50px;
}

.row .col.sd1 {
  width: 8.3333333333%;
  margin-left: auto;
  left: auto;
  right: auto;
}

.row .col.sd2 {
  width: 16.6666666667%;
  margin-left: auto;
  left: auto;
  right: auto;
}

.row .col.sd3 {
  width: 25%;
  margin-left: auto;
  left: auto;
  right: auto;
}

.row .col.sd4 {
  width: 33.3333333333%;
  margin-left: auto;
  left: auto;
  right: auto;
}

.row .col.sd5 {
  width: 41.6666666667%;
  margin-left: auto;
  left: auto;
  right: auto;
}

.row .col.sd6 {
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: auto;
  left: auto;
  right: auto;
}

.row .col.sd7 {
  width: 58.3333333333%;
  margin-left: auto;
  left: auto;
  right: auto;
}

.row .col.sd8 {
  width: 66.6666666667%;
  margin-left: auto;
  left: auto;
  right: auto;
}

.row .col.sd9 {
  width: 75%;
  margin-left: auto;
  left: auto;
  right: auto;
}

.row .col.sd10 {
  width: 83.3333333333%;
  margin-left: auto;
  left: auto;
  right: auto;
}

.row .col.sd11 {
  width: 91.6666666667%;
  margin-left: auto;
  left: auto;
  right: auto;
}

.row .col.sd12 {
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  left: auto;
  right: auto;
}

.c {
  background: red;
  padding: 10px;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 601px) {
  .row .col.md1 {
    width: 8.3333333333%;
    margin-left: auto;
    left: auto;
    right: auto;
  }
  .row .col.md2 {
    width: 16.6666666667%;
    margin-left: auto;
    left: auto;
    right: auto;
  }
  .row .col.md3 {
    width: 25%;
    margin-left: auto;
    left: auto;
    right: auto;
  }
  .row .col.md4 {
    width: 33.3333333333%;
    margin-left: auto;
    left: auto;
    right: auto;
  }
  .row .col.md5 {
    width: 41.6666666667%;
    margin-left: auto;
    left: auto;
    right: auto;
  }
  .row .col.md6 {
    width: 50%;
    margin-left: auto;
    left: auto;
    right: auto;
  }
  .row .col.md7 {
    width: 58.3333333333%;
    margin-left: auto;
    left: auto;
    right: auto;
  }
  .row .col.md8 {
    width: 66.6666666667%;
    margin-left: auto;
    left: auto;
    right: auto;
  }
  .row .col.md9 {
    width: 75%;
    margin-left: auto;
    left: auto;
    right: auto;
  }
  .row .col.md10 {
    width: 83.3333333333%;
    margin-left: auto;
    left: auto;
    right: auto;
  }
  .row .col.md11 {
    width: 91.6666666667%;
    margin-left: auto;
    left: auto;
    right: auto;
  }
  .row .col.md12 {
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    left: auto;
    right: auto;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 993px) {
  .row .col.ld1 {
    width: 8.3333333333%;
    margin-left: auto;
    left: auto;
    right: auto;
  }
  .row .col.ld2 {
    width: 16.6666666667%;
    margin-left: auto;
    left: auto;
    right: auto;
  }
  .row .col.ld3 {
    width: 25%;
    margin-left: auto;
    left: auto;
    right: auto;
  }
  .row .col.ld4 {
    width: 33.3333333333%;
    margin-left: auto;
    left: auto;
    right: auto;
  }
  .row .col.ld5 {
    width: 41.6666666667%;
    margin-left: auto;
    left: auto;
    right: auto;
  }
  .row .col.ld6 {
    width: 50%;
    margin-left: auto;
    left: auto;
    right: auto;
  }
  .row .col.ld7 {
    width: 58.3333333333%;
    margin-left: auto;
    left: auto;
    right: auto;
  }
  .row .col.ld8 {
    width: 66.6666666667%;
    margin-left: auto;
    left: auto;
    right: auto;
  }
  .row .col.ld9 {
    width: 75%;
    margin-left: auto;
    left: auto;
    right: auto;
  }
  .row .col.ld10 {
    width: 83.3333333333%;
    margin-left: auto;
    left: auto;
    right: auto;
  }
  .row .col.ld11 {
    width: 91.6666666667%;
    margin-left: auto;
    left: auto;
    right: auto;
  }
  .row .col.ld12 {
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    left: auto;
    right: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row ">
  <div class="col sd12 md6 ld4">
    <div class="c"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col sd12 md6 ld4">
    <div class="c"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col sd12 md6 ld4">
    <div class="c"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col sd12 md6 ld4">
    <div class="c"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col sd12 md6 ld4">
    <div class="c"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col sd12 md6 ld4">
    <div class="c"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col sd12 md6 ld4">
    <div class="c"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col sd12 md6 ld4">
    <div class="c"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Screenshot on mobile:

[image: ScreenShot from mobile device]

Comment: Can you tell us what the issue was coming in mobile device?

Comment: on desktop when the browser window size is reduced each column element will be stacked (one below the other) , same should reflect in mobile device , but you can see that two column elements are next to each other , I need them to be stacked.. @Minal Chauhan

Answer (score 0):

Add meta tag if you don't have it already

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: yea  I have included the **viewport**

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have made a very novice error in the code.

The normal Responsive designs are developed across various Screen Device, where you mention the width range of the Screen devices.

Here in your code, you have only mentioned min-width, whereas you also have to mention the max-width of the device screen, or you can simply change your min-width to max-width.

Corrected Code snippet:

```
.col .row {
  margin-left: -0.75rem;
  margin-right: -0.75rem;
}

..
..
..

.c {
  background: red;
  padding: 10px;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 601px) {
  .row .col.md1 {
    width: 8.3333333333%;
    margin-left: auto;
    left: auto;
    right: auto;
  }
  ..
  ..
  ..
  .row .col.md12 {
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    left: auto;
    right: auto;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 993px) {
  .row .col.ld1 {
    width: 8.3333333333%;
    margin-left: auto;
    left: auto;
    right: auto;
  }
  ..
  ..
  ..
  .row .col.ld12 {
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    left: auto;
    right: auto;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to Change in media query width:

- 601px  to  768px (for Ipad)
- 993px to 1025px (for small laptop)

```css
.col .row {
  margin-left: -0.75rem;
  margin-right: -0.75rem;
}

.row {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.row .col {
  float: left;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0 0.75rem;
  min-height: 50px;
}

.row .col.sd1 {
  width: 8.3333333333%;
  margin-left: auto;
  left: auto;
  right: auto;
}

.row .col.sd2 {
  width: 16.6666666667%;
  margin-left: auto;
  left: auto;
  right: auto;
}

.row .col.sd3 {
  width: 25%;
  margin-left: auto;
  left: auto;
  right: auto;
}

.row .col.sd4 {
  width: 33.3333333333%;
  margin-left: auto;
  left: auto;
  right: auto;
}

.row .col.sd5 {
  width: 41.6666666667%;
  margin-left: auto;
  left: auto;
  right: auto;
}

.row .col.sd6 {
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: auto;
  left: auto;
  right: auto;
}

.row .col.sd7 {
  width: 58.3333333333%;
  margin-left: auto;
  left: auto;
  right: auto;
}

.row .col.sd8 {
  width: 66.6666666667%;
  margin-left: auto;
  left: auto;
  right: auto;
}

.row .col.sd9 {
  width: 75%;
  margin-left: auto;
  left: auto;
  right: auto;
}

.row .col.sd10 {
  width: 83.3333333333%;
  margin-left: auto;
  left: auto;
  right: auto;
}

.row .col.sd11 {
  width: 91.6666666667%;
  margin-left: auto;
  left: auto;
  right: auto;
}

.row .col.sd12 {
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  left: auto;
  right: auto;
}

.c {
  background: red;
  padding: 10px;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .row .col.md1 {
    width: 8.3333333333%;
    margin-left: auto;
    left: auto;
    right: auto;
  }
  .row .col.md2 {
    width: 16.6666666667%;
    margin-left: auto;
    left: auto;
    right: auto;
  }
  .row .col.md3 {
    width: 25%;
    margin-left: auto;
    left: auto;
    right: auto;
  }
  .row .col.md4 {
    width: 33.3333333333%;
    margin-left: auto;
    left: auto;
    right: auto;
  }
  .row .col.md5 {
    width: 41.6666666667%;
    margin-left: auto;
    left: auto;
    right: auto;
  }
  .row .col.md6 {
    width: 50%;
    margin-left: auto;
    left: auto;
    right: auto;
  }
  .row .col.md7 {
    width: 58.3333333333%;
    margin-left: auto;
    left: auto;
    right: auto;
  }
  .row .col.md8 {
    width: 66.6666666667%;
    margin-left: auto;
    left: auto;
    right: auto;
  }
  .row .col.md9 {
    width: 75%;
    margin-left: auto;
    left: auto;
    right: auto;
  }
  .row .col.md10 {
    width: 83.3333333333%;
    margin-left: auto;
    left: auto;
    right: auto;
  }
  .row .col.md11 {
    width: 91.6666666667%;
    margin-left: auto;
    left: auto;
    right: auto;
  }
  .row .col.md12 {
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    left: auto;
    right: auto;
  }
}


@media only screen and (min-width: 1025px) {
  .row .col.ld1 {
    width: 8.3333333333%;
    margin-left: auto;
    left: auto;
    right: auto;
  }
  .row .col.ld2 {
    width: 16.6666666667%;
    margin-left: auto;
    left: auto;
    right: auto;
  }
  .row .col.ld3 {
    width: 25%;
    margin-left: auto;
    left: auto;
    right: auto;
  }
  .row .col.ld4 {
    width: 33.3333333333%;
    margin-left: auto;
    left: auto;
    right: auto;
  }
  .row .col.ld5 {
    width: 41.6666666667%;
    margin-left: auto;
    left: auto;
    right: auto;
  }
  .row .col.ld6 {
    width: 50%;
    margin-left: auto;
    left: auto;
    right: auto;
  }
  .row .col.ld7 {
    width: 58.3333333333%;
    margin-left: auto;
    left: auto;
    right: auto;
  }
  .row .col.ld8 {
    width: 66.6666666667%;
    margin-left: auto;
    left: auto;
    right: auto;
  }
  .row .col.ld9 {
    width: 75%;
    margin-left: auto;
    left: auto;
    right: auto;
  }
  .row .col.ld10 {
    width: 83.3333333333%;
    margin-left: auto;
    left: auto;
    right: auto;
  }
  .row .col.ld11 {
    width: 91.6666666667%;
    margin-left: auto;
    left: auto;
    right: auto;
  }
  .row .col.ld12 {
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    left: auto;
    right: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row ">
  <div class="col sd12 md6 ld4">
    <div class="c"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col sd12 md6 ld4">
    <div class="c"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col sd12 md6 ld4">
    <div class="c"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col sd12 md6 ld4">
    <div class="c"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col sd12 md6 ld4">
    <div class="c"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col sd12 md6 ld4">
    <div class="c"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col sd12 md6 ld4">
    <div class="c"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col sd12 md6 ld4">
    <div class="c"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```